# TortoiseHg export pre-commit versions of changed files

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

In TortoiseHg one can export changed files by right-clicking revision, then choosing Export -> Archive... This way I can copy changed files to a separate folder. But how do I export pre-commit versions of changed files? I need two folders, like "before" and "after". Currently I can only have "after" files with post-commit versions of the changed files.

Answer (score 1):

> But how do I export pre-commit versions of changed files?

"Pre-commit" for *some changeset* is "post-commit" for changeset, which was previous for objects in question. You have just to detect it.

If you want state of the **whole repo** before and after some changeset, they will be `$CSET` and `$CSET-1`, obviously

If you want to perform archiving of pre-commit and post-commit state of only some subdir inside repository, you must to find older point of archiving, and you have at least two ways in pure TortoiseHG to do it (plus some CLI-ways outside this study):

- In you preferred file-manager (not in THG), select needed folder in repository and in TortoiseHG context menu `Revision History` (screenshot for my folder `/lang` in repository)

[image: THG Menu]

You'll get standard TortoiseHG's workbench window with revisions-list

[image: Filtered view]

with small changes:

1. it will be filtered view, in which some changesets are skipped (note **1** selection for pre-32 history): missed changesets didn't touch directory in questions
2. Visible `Filter Toolbar` (see **2**) show revset, applied to revlist in order to get our subset

   - From other side, revset is easy understandable (while reading `hg help revsets` is recommended) and writing revset from scratch by hand may be second and faster way: in file('path:SOMEPATH') only SOMEPATH is variable part with easy rules: a) Unix-type slashes `/` used on any platform if subdir|file is deeper, than root|immediate parent of root of repo b) leading and trailing slashes in path not used. I.e for dir in repo `\plugins\serendipity_event_assigncategories\UTF-8\`  revset will be `file('path:plugins/serendipity_event_assigncategories/UTF-8')`

At last, when you have in Workbench both revisions (*needed* and *previous*) you can in context menu of these revisions `Export` -> `Archive`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation (https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/archive and https://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.0/archive.html) for hg archive command, it appears that the code must have a revision number to export, otherwise by default, the revision used is the parent of the working directory; use -r/--rev to specify a different revision.

`thg archive -r [REV] -t [TYPE] [DEST]`

So if a  `-r [REV]`  isn't supplied, then the tip (latest committed code set) will be exported. This looks like you cannot specify the working directory like you had wanted to do.

Is there a reason you don't want to commit these changes? You could always commit these to an different branch, then archive/export them so the default branch remains intact.

Comment: I want to export committed changes; committing changes is not a problem; the only problem is that I need both pre-commit and post-commit states of the changed files; and I need only changed files, not all version-controlled files

Comment: Oh okay. Something similar has been asked previously, does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871522/mercurial-how-do-i-create-a-zip-of-files-changed-between-two-revisions